# unordered list- first list item is raised in position

Tags: html, css, angular

Does anybody know why the first li item is raised in its position. And it only happens when I add id or class to the div.

[image]

Here is code:

```
<div id="pickList">
    <ul *ngFor="let channel of currentPickSelection">
      <li class="list-group-item" style="float:Left;margin:1px;" (dragover)="onDragOver(channel[0])" (drop)="onDrop()"
      [ngStyle]="{'background-color': channel[0].compChannel[0].compChannelLogo.length !== 0 ? '#8EC0D1' : 'aliceblue' }">
        <ng-container *ngIf="channel[0].compChannel[0].compChannelLogo.length !== 0; else noCompChannel">
          <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel[0].logo }}" alt="{{ channel[0].channel }}" width="50" height="50">
          <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel[0].compChannel[0].compChannelLogo }}" alt="{{ channel[0].compChannel[0].compChannelName }}"
            width="50" height="50">
        </ng-container>
        <br>
        <div align="center">
          <strong>
            <font size="2">{{ channel[0].pickCode }}</font>
          </strong>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#pickList {
  height:565px;
  scroll-behavior: auto;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the element above is pushing them down. I don't think the class/ID thing is a factor. That said, we can't do much without a demo or a markup snippet without a bunch of Angular stuff in it. This is a CSS question.

Comment: @isherwood But when I remove the id or the class, it works perfect

Comment: why dont you check where is that styling coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out this way, by adding an extra div in between

```
 <div class="row pickList" align="center">
    <div>
      <ul *ngFor="let channel of currentPickSelection">
        <li class="list-group-item" style="float:Left;margin:1px;" (dragover)="onDragOver(channel[0])" (drop)="onDrop()" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': channel[0].compChannel[0].compChannelLogo.length !== 0 ? '#8EC0D1' : 'aliceblue' }">
          <ng-container *ngIf="channel[0].compChannel[0].compChannelLogo.length !== 0; else noCompChannel">
            <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel[0].logo }}" alt="{{ channel[0].channel }}" width="50" height="50">
            <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel[0].compChannel[0].compChannelLogo }}" alt="{{ channel[0].compChannel[0].compChannelName }}"
              width="50" height="50">
          </ng-container>
          <br>
          <div align="center">
            <strong>
              <font size="2">{{ channel[0].pickCode }}</font>
            </strong>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```